# Programmatically Stopping a Windows Service from a Web App

Tags: windows-services, windows-server-2008, java-ee-6

I have a web application running in a GlassFish 3.1 service on Windows 7 and Server 2008. I would like this application to be able to control a number of other services on the same machine. In particular I want it to be able to start and stop Tomcat services.

Essentially the application is acting as a controller for other applications I deploy on the machine so I can set any security necessary on the controlled applications.

I notice that .Net has a ServiceController class so I'm assuming that programmatic control is possible but I would very strongly prefer a pure Java solution if possible.

All the searches I've done turn up a lot of information about running Java as a service and not much on controlling services from Java. Is what I'm trying to do possible? What security hoops will I need to jump through?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do Runtime.exec("net stop tomcat6"). Of course tomcat6 can be replaced with any other service name.
Also check out this tutorial
http://www.java-samples.com/showtutorial.php?tutorialid=8

Comment: I should have said that I'm aware of Runtime.exec but it won't work in this situation due to security issues. As far as I'm aware services can't just start and stop each other by default. I think [this posting](http://serverfault.com/questions/187302/how-do-i-grant-start-stop-restart-permissions-on-a-service-to-an-arbitrary-user) on ServerFault goes a long way to answering the question.